# Is there a way to achieve the color to color fade effect of firework particles with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a pack and would like to know if there is a way to summon color changing particles, like the ones in the firework. I'm trying to get some particles that change from lime to yellow

here is an example firework with the particles I want to summon, I could use summon fireworks but they would have to explode immediately with no sound effect

```
/give @p firework_rocket{Fireworks:{Flight:1,Explosions:[{Type:0,Flicker:0,Trail:0,Colors:[I;4312372],FadeColors:[I;14602026]}]}} 1
```

is it possible to achieve this with the /particle command? it would be nice because then I can control the speed and the ammount

Comment: The particle command is very weird. At least the syntax given in the [wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/particle) is not fully correct, because for examle `/particle block stone` is valid (it just doesn't seem to do anything). Silencing rockets does not seem to be possible, they ignore the `Silent` tag if you give it to them.